# C# - Geocode pharmacy by name and location

Tags: c#, google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-api

How can I find the coordinates of a pharmacy by it name and location?

I'm trying to search with the Google geocode API like this:

```
var pharmacyName = "Farmácia Ereirense";
var address = "Cartaxo, Santarém";

var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + pharmacyName + ", " + address + "&sensor=false";
```

but I only got `ZERO_RESULTS` on the GeoResponse Status, and if I google "*Farmácia Ereirense, Cartaxo, Santarém*" it found the right location...

I already tried to do:

```
var pharmacyName = "Farmácia Ereirense";
var address = "Cartaxo, Santarém";

var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?name=" + pharmacyName + ", " + address + "&key=" + apiKey;
```

but I got the `INVALID_REQUEST` result.

[Documentation I based on](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution! We can do a Text Search request like this:

```
var pharmacyName = "Farmácia Ereirense";
var address = "Cartaxo, Santarém";

var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=" + pharmacyName + ", " + address + "&key=" + apiKey;
```

And it works just fine, like Google's search.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)